# What is "Symbol Highlight Transient State"?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, minibuffer

Pressing * (spacemacs/enter-ahs-forward) works like visual star in Vim, except for the mini buffer:
[image]
What is "Symbol Highlight Transient State" in the mini buffer about?
Where is the documentation that explains the minibuffer options?:

```
                                        [r] change range  [R] reset   [e] iedit
                    [d/D] next/previous definition
[KEY] exits state  [KEY] will not exit
```

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there's that much documentation on that (and I've rebound those keys personally), but I believe it's spacemacs' integration of `auto-highlight-symbol.el`, which is in various files, including `spacemacs/layers/+spacemacs/spacemacs-navigation/funcs.el`.  You can find out a bit by reading those files.  The little key summary there probably indicates spacemacs has defined a `hydra` to implement this, though I'm not actually sure where that's defined.

You can see from those filenames that the integration is provided by layer `spacemacs-navigation`, for which you'd be able to find docs using `SPC h l spacemacs-navigation RET` -- but that's just a stub "TODO" file at the time of writing.

Quoting from `auto-highlight-symbol.el`:

```
;;  A minor mode for emacs.
;;
;;   * automatic highlighting current symbol like eclipse IDE.
;;   * cycle through highlighted locations.
;;   * can specify the range to highlight.
;;   * can edit the highlighted symbols at a time.
```

I found that out by opening the `spacemacs` directory in dired, then searching for the string you mentioned using `SPC /`, then `SPC h d f auto-highlight-symbol RET` and clicking on the link to visit that file.

I believe "iedit" is a multi-line editing package, so presumably that will start a multi-line editing session on the current matches?  Why not try the keys and see what they do?